# Buttons on Header don't scroll to desired section by clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am finishing a website from a Udemy course project and followed all the steps but i still have a problem. I want the two buttons on my Website to scroll to the desired section by clicking on them. The buttons: "I'm Hungry" should bring me to the "Plans" and "Show me More" should bring me to the section "Features".

The link to the website is http://omnifood.lavaspace.de
You can view the source code or inspect with developer tools.

First part of HTML

```
     <div class="hero-text-box">

            <h1> Goodbye junk food. <br> Hello super healthy meals. </h1>
            <a class="btn btn-full js--scroll-to-plans" href="#" > I'm hungry </a>
            <a class="btn btn-ghost js--scroll-to-start" href="#"> Show me more </a>



        </div>


    </header>

    <section class="section-features js--section-features" id="features">
        <div class="row">
```

and this HTML section

```
    <section class="section-plans js--section-plans" id="plans">
        <div class="row">
            <h2>Start eating healthy today</h2>
        </div>
```

Here are the concerning CSS parts

```
     /* BUTTONS */

    .btn:link,
    .btn:visited,
    input[type=submit]{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 200px;
        transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;

    }
    .btn-full,
    .btn-ghost {
        margin-top: 3px;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
    }



    .btn-full:link,
    .btn-full:visited,
    input[type=submit]{

        background-color: #e67e22;
        border: 1px solid #e67e22;
        color: #fff;
        margin-right: 15px;


    }

    .btn-ghost:link,
    .btn-ghost:visited {

        border: 1px solid #e67e22;
        color: #e67e22;
    }

    .btn:hover,
    .btn:active,
    input[type=submit]:hover,
    input[type=submit]:active {
        background-color: #cf6d17;



    }

    .btn-full:hover,
    .btn-full:active,
    input[type=submit] {

        border: 1px solid #cf6d17;


    }

    .btn-ghost:hover,
    .btn-ghost:active {

        border: 1px solid #cf6d17;
        color: #fff;


    }

    .hero-text-box {
        position: absolute;
        width: 1140px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);



    }

     .section-plans {
        background-color: #f4f4f4;


    }

     .section-features .long-copy  {
        margin-bottom: 30px;


    }
```

And here's the Javascript Code which should be commanding the buttons to scroll to the section. I pasted all, because there might be some conflicts between JS functions, causing the scroll not to work.

```
        /* STICKY NAVIGATION */


        $(document).ready(function() {


            $('.js--section-features').waypoint(function(direction){
                if(direction == "down"){
                    $('nav').addClass('sticky');
                }else{
                    $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
                }
            }, {
                offset: '120px;'
            });


        /* SCROLL BUTTONS */




            $('.js--scroll-to-plans').click(function (){
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.js--section-plans').offset().top}, 1000);
        });

            $('.js--scroll-to-start').click(function (){
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.js--section-features').offset().top}, 1000);
            });

        });  





        $('a[href*="#"]').on('click',function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var target = this.hash;
         var $target = $(target);
         $('html, body').stop().animate({
          'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
         }, 900, 'swing', function () {
          window.location.hash = target;
         });
        });                      

        // Select all links with hashes
        $('a[href*="#"]')
          // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
          .not('[href="#"]')
          .not('[href="#0"]')
          .click(function(event) {
            // On-page links
            if (
              location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
              && 
              location.hostname == this.hostname
            ) {
              // Figure out element to scroll to
              var target = $(this.hash);
              target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
              // Does a scroll target exist?
              if (target.length) {
                // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000, function() {
                  // Callback after animation
                  // Must change focus!
                  var $target = $(target);
                  $target.focus();
                  if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
                    return false;
                  } else {
                    $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
                    $target.focus(); // Set focus again
                  };
                });
              }
            }
          });



        /* ANIMATIONS ON SCROLL */


        $('.js--wp-1').waypoint(function(direction) {
            $('.js--wp-1').addClass('animated fadeIn')


        }, {
            offset: '50%'
        });

        $('.js--wp-2').waypoint(function(direction) {
            $('.js--wp-2').addClass('animated fadeInUp')


        }, {
            offset: '50%'
        });

        $('.js--wp-3').waypoint(function(direction) {
            $('.js--wp-3').addClass('animated fadeIn')


        }, {
            offset: '50%'
        });

        $('.js--wp-4').waypoint(function(direction) {
            $('.js--wp-4').addClass('animated pulse')


        }, {
            offset: '50%'
        });

        /* MOBILE MENU */

        $('.js--nav-icon').click(function(){
            var nav =$('.js--main-nav');
            var icon = $('.js--nav-icon');

            nav.slideToggle(200);
            if (icon.hasClass('ion-navicon-round')) {
                icon.addClass('ion-close-round');
                icon.removeClass('ion-navicon-round');

            }   else { 
                icon.addclass('ion-navicon-round');
                icon.removeClass('ion-close-round');


            }




        });

        /* MAPS */

        var map = new GMaps({
              el: '#map',
              lat: -12.043333,
              lng: -77.028333
            });
```

Comment: Hi, can you share some code instead of just a link ?

Comment: Please go read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: i added some code, here you go, my apologies.

Comment: I edit my solution

Answer (score 0):

You can put a generic solution by putting the section id in the href

```
<a href=“#plans"> I'm hungry  </a>
```

and use the below jQuery code :

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
  }, 1000);
  return false;
});
```